# How to make 100% height behave as expected within a scrolling, fixed position header?

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I'm trying to build a responsive header component for a site. The header has `position: fixed` so that it doesn't scroll, but contains a horizontally scrolling list of options.

I used [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll) to build the horizontally-scrolling internals so that the list of header items could be scrolled but no scrollbar would be displayed. Check out the code below, and see it working in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmjh0as1/1/).

### HTML

```
<body>
    <main class="fixed-container">
        <div class="scroll-container">
            <ul class="scroll-list">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
.fixed-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.scroll-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}
.scroll-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.scroll-list li {
  flex: 1 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

`<div class="scroll-container">`, with `height: 100%`, fills the height of the `<main class="fixed-container">` as expected. However the `<ul>` within the div, which also has `height: 100%`, does not fill the height of its parent. There is space between the red borders at the bottom of the `<li>`s within and the black border at the bottom of the `<main class="fixed-container">`.

*Note that if `overflow-x: auto` and `overflow-y: hidden` are removed from `<div class="scroll-container">`, or if `right: 0` is removed from `<main class="fixed-container">` then the heights behave as expected and the red borders are flush with the top of the black border.*

How can I get the `<ul>` to fit the height of its parent so that the red borders sit directly on top of the black border?

Comment: how about `overflow-x: overlay;`

Comment: Strange behavior. It appears that the gap is caused by the browser making space for the scrollbar track from the `overflow` rules on `.scroll-container`.

Comment: `overflow: overlay` is not in the spec. I wouldn't rely on it. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#overflow

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeMcCaughan! I've added the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by changing the `.scroll-container` rule like this, where instead of setting a bottom padding, you increase its height

```
.scroll-container {
  height: calc(100% + 17px);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```css
.fixed-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.scroll-container {
  height: calc(100% + 17px);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.scroll-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.scroll-list li {
  flex: 1 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <main class="fixed-container">
  <div class="scroll-container">
   <ul class="scroll-list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </main>
```

Comment: Thanks, LGSon, this does work! I'm going to hold out in the hope that another solution can explain the problem and propose a solution that doesn't involve experimental CSS tech, but very much appreciate the help.

Comment: @jesse501 Well, [CSS Calc](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#functional-notations) is not _experimental_ in that manner that it will stop working, so no worries there. Its been around since IE9, and has much better browser support than the `flexbox` you use, so you most likely won't get a better solution to the problem

Comment: @jesse501 Let me know if my answer worked, or were helpful, and can be accepted and/or upvoted, or else I delete it.